# Limit recursive user re-connections using socket handshake

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am trying to prevent user recursive re-connections to my server, the thing is like this:
Before doing initializing user through required actions i want to save his unique INFO (that what i want ask you, which data is the best to define the user unique data, if they are using firewall, or the same router, and can be connected through mobile and web-browser) address into the map and add the counter of re-connection and add the time stamp of 10 sec. 
if user not trying to connect more then 10 times in 10 sec, so it is ok and i can continue executing of required login functions, otherwise i want to emit to this user through the socket error message.

Comment: Mac address together with unique/random id generated by the client?

Comment: when user re-connected, it generate new socket always, so i can't count on this.